# Office.js API for PowerPoint

Tags: office-js

I just start working on new project to create Add-in for Power Point documents. 
I spent a lot of time browsing the [documentation](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/powerpoint/powerpoint-add-ins) without finding what I want. It seems that I'm missing something about this documentation.

I was excepting to see all objects (with their properties and methods) like Microsoft did with C#, VB ... but that's not the case. For example, I'm looking for a way to get custom properties for a given Power Point document.

Within my js file, I did this:

```
    var pptDocument = Office.context.document;
    pptDocument.loadCustomPropertiesAsync(customPropsCallback);
```

I used `loadCustomPropertiesAsync` because It's implemented with outlook.
What function can I use here in this specific case?

In general, How can I see all methods and properties of the `document` object in Power Point Add-in?

**EDIT:**

What I want to achieve?

Within my Add-in, I would like to add (or update if exists) a custom property. So When I navigate to my PPT custom properties table, I can see that custom property in the properties table.
Of course, I want to save the changes so If I close and open the file, the custom property remains there.

Navigate to custom properties in Power Point 2016: 
File => Info => Properties => Advanced Properties => Custom tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are referring to custom document properties. Unfortunately in PPT is still not possible to get them. It is in Word and very soon in Excel. Please vote for this feature in UserVoice, who we consider to prioritize what we'll deliver in the future. thanks!

btw this is how to do it in word.

```js
function readCustomDocumentProperties() {
    Word.run(function (context) {
        var properties = context.document.properties.customProperties;
        context.load(properties);
        return context.sync()
            .then(function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < properties.items.length; i++)
                    console.log("Property Name:" + properties.items[i].key + ";Type=" + properties.items[i].type + "; Property Value=" + properties.items[i].value);
            })
            .catch(OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log);
    })
}
```

Comment: Is there a work around for now to add/edit a custom document property?

Comment: Also, I can't see the function to get custom properties in Word

Comment: You can use the settings object to store custom properties. I would need more details on your scenario to see if this will help. Basically the settings object is a property bag you can store setting and its stored with the PPT doc, similar to a custom property, but it never shows up on the UI. so again if i can get more details will be great..

Comment: please check my answer I appended  how to get custom properties in word.

Comment: Thanks @Juan, In my case, What should I put instead of `Word.run`? According to your suggestion, I can use `document.settings` instead of `document.properties.customProperties` ?

Comment: you need to use Word.run, that's just how the API works. That's the short story, the long story is that you are trying to use the V1 APIs (known as "common APIs") in office 2016 we added application specific APIs for Word and Excel and for those you need to use the new Syntax (i.e. Word.run/Excel.run)

Comment: If I want to open PPT document from Desktop Application (let's say C# app), Can I still access and edit `settings` object?